# Is it natural to say you wonder what yourself (could) have been doing?

Tags: idiomatic-language, sentence-usage

Alan is hanging out with Alice alone in the forest when they get caught by Alan's girlfriend Betty. Feeling agitated, Betty confronts them, asking what they two were doing there. Wanting to make Betty even more jealous, Alice mischievously replies,

> Gee, **I wonder what we could've been doing**. I think you can imagine what it was.

Hey! You don't know what yourself could've been doing? I wonder if this type of playful expressions are natural.

Comment: Sounds like a bad script from a 1950s B-movie.

Comment: As you say, it's mischievous. The implied meaning is not that Alice doesn't know, but that what Betty imagines they were doing is the truth.

Comment: @KateBunting Alice and Alan aren't in that kind of relationship, and weren't doing anything inappropriate. She's just teasing Betty.

Comment: Well, then she's hinting that it _might_ have been the truth,.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is totally natural! I've heard and read that sort of sarcasm before. It's not subtle and implies that Alice is really just playing with Betty.